# Cant find the mistake in this code, page shows up blank

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header('Location: login.php');
exit();
}
include('includes/db_connect.php');
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = ("SELECT file_id FROM files WHERE user_id='$userid'");
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows ===1){
echo "<a href="index.php">Sorry you have already uploaded a file, to delete the current file and upload another please select retieve file from the homepage</a>";
}else{
echo "you can upload a file";
}
?>
```

The above checks to see if the user has uploaded a file. It does this by seeing if their is a file with their user id. some reason the page is just blank when loaded.

include just hold the connection string

been looking at this for ages, help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: It's on the first `echo` line. Check out the formatting in the editor above and it should be quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

This line has a syntax error:

`echo "<a href="index.php">Sorry you have already uploaded a file, to delete the current file and upload another please select retieve file from the homepage</a>";`

If you define a string with double quotes (`"`), you must escape all double quotes contained in the string.

Replace it with this:

`echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Sorry you have already uploaded a file, to delete the current file and upload another please select retieve file from the homepage</a>";`

Comment: Thank you so much, knew it would be something so simple.

Comment: Besides that: place your error-reporting-settings in a .htaccess-file (or /etc/php.ini, apache-config etc). That way parse-errors will be displayed with including line-number and relevant other data. When you set it in the same file (like now), PHP can't parse that file, so the ini_set is never been called and you stay stuck with your error.